# Button doesn't work when I'm back on starter page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I want to implement Navigation Drawer by using panel with list of buttons (each openning other page). Problem occurs when I go back to the previous page and I try to open panel again. Button which is supposed to do that doesn't work, it only lights up in blue.

Start 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4caLy.jpg

Open panel
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7IQ2.jpg

Back in first page,  button does not work
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9Smo.jpg

Here's my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="firstPage">
      <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel" data-display="overlay"> 
        <h2>Menu</h2>
        <br/>
        <ul data-role="listview">
              <li><a href="#firstPage" data-rel="close" >First Page</a></li>
              <li><a href="#secondPage" data-rel="close" >Second Page</a></li>
        </ul>       
      </div> 

      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>First Page</h1>
        <a href="#myPanel" class="ui-btn ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Open Panel</a>
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>FirstPage</p>
      </div>
    </div> 


    <div data-role="page" id="secondPage">
      <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel" data-display="overlay"> 
        <h2>Menu</h2>
        <br/>
        <ul data-role="listview">
              <li><a href="#firstPage" data-rel="close" >First Page</a></li>
              <li><a href="#secondPage" data-rel="close" >Second Page</a></li>
        </ul>       
      </div> 

      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Second Page</h1>
        <a href="#myPanel" class="ui-btn ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Open Panel</a>
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>Second Page</p>
      </div>            

</body>
```

Any advice or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 panel divs with same ID `id="myPanel"`

changing the id of second panel should resolve the issue.